# What's the iOS < 9 alternative to CNLabeledValue?

Tags: swift, uitableview, contacts, addressbook, didselectrowatindexpath

I have implemented both the framework for `Contact` and `AddressBook` in order to fetch contacts from the contact book for users both above and below `iOS` 9. In order to press a row to access another `view` to see the contact information I have used `CNLabeledValue` in `didSelectRowAt` like this:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    switch((number as! CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber> ).label){
        case CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile:phoneContact?.mobilePhone = (number as! CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>).value.stringValue
        case CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone:phoneContact?.mobilePhone = (number as! CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>).value.stringValue
        case CNLabelPhoneNumberMain:phoneContact?.mobilePhone = (number as! CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>).value.stringValue
        case CNLabelHome:phoneContact?.homePhone = (number as! CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>).value.stringValue
        case CNLabelWork:phoneContact?.workPhone = (number as! CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>).value.stringValue
        default:phoneContact?.mobilePhone = (number as! CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>).value.stringValue
        }
} else {
   // Fallback on earlier versions

   }
```

The `ContactBook` code works, but what was used before `CNLabeledValue` before `iOS 9`? Is there a framework to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Contacts framework (`CN*`) was added in iOS 9. Before that, we used the [AddressBook framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook). There is no exact equivalent to CNLabledValue there. The closest is ABMultiValue, which is a CoreFoundation type.

Note that the current docs often suggest that some of these types only exist in macOS 12+, but that's not correct. Many of these did exist on older versions of iOS.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it! :)